# Can't run Prefect Orion on mac

Tags: orchestration, prefect

I am working on mac machine and using Prefect orion in one of my projects, and getting error whenever I start Prefect Orion using `prefect orion start` command.

I have installed prefect==2.3.2 under the conda virtual environment

```
INFO:     Started server process [67822]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
ERROR:    Traceback (most recent call last):
.
.
.
.
.
.
.


/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 265, in _catch_revision_errors
    raise util.CommandError(resolution) from re
***alembic.util.exc.CommandError: Can't locate revision identified by 'af52717cf201'
***
ERROR:    Application startup failed. Exiting.
Orion stopped!
```

It's showing  against "Server type" when I run "prefect version"
What could be the possible issue here?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Do you have the possibility of removing the DB to start from scratch? Your error looks like a migration issue, which shouldn't occur if you start with a fresh DB:

```
rm ~/.prefect/orion.db
prefect orion start
```

Comment: It's solved! Thanks a lot! That was the case.